# Lambda com contextos diferentes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, expressões-lambda

Existe alguma forma de joinar duas ou mais tabelas usando Lambda e dois contextos diferentes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pode utilizar [`Linq To Objects`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397919.aspx), ou seja, manipulando dados em memória, recomendado também [`AsNoTrancking()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679352%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) para não deixar em cache as consultas.

***Exemplo***

```cs
IList<Pessoa> Pessoas = null;
using (Dba1 dba1 = new Dba1())
{
    Pessoas = dba1.Pessoa.AsNoTracking().ToList();
}


IList<Telefone> Telefones = null;
using (Dba2 dba2 = new Dba2())
{
    Telefones = dba2.Telefone.AsNoTracking().ToList();
}


Pessoas.Join(Telefones, x => x.Id, g => g.PessoaId, (x, g) => new { x, g })
       .Select(s => new
       {
           s.g.Ddd, 
           s.g.Numero, 
           s.g.PessoaId,
           s.x.Nome
       }).ToList();
```

**Obs:** *Não é muito performático, mas, em casos específicos podem ser bem utilizado, não pode virar regra da sua aplicação*.

*Referências:*

- [Linq To Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397919.aspx)
- [DbExtensions.AsNoTracking Method (IQueryable)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679352%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)